# How to access the secondary(front) camera using sencha/phoneGap?

Tags: html, cordova, extjs

I am new to mobile world so this might be  a trivial question. I am trying (but unable) to access the front camera to take pictures for an app which i plan to build using a html5/js mobile framework like sencha touch/ phonegap . Any help or alternative for this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the **front camera** in appcelerator which is a popular html5/js mobile app building framework. But to create a custom camera app you need to go native.

```
if (Ti.Media.camera == Ti.Media.CAMERA_FRONT)
        {
            cameraType.title = "front";
            Ti.Media.switchCamera(Ti.Media.CAMERA_REAR);
        }
        else
        {
            cameraType.title = "rear";
            Ti.Media.switchCamera(Ti.Media.CAMERA_FRONT);
        }
```

For more details refer the question on the [appcelerator forum](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/142088/remember-settings-each-time-camera-is-opened).